# Application of complex number s for solutions to a quadratic example from Spivak - Ch.25 - pg 522 - 2nd ed

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-numbers, proof-explanation, intuition

I had a question of some algebra the author used to explain an idea. As stated before, it comes from *Spivak's Calculus - Ch 25 - pg. 522 - 2nd ed*. The example in question revolves around the use of complex numbers and is the following:

[image]

In particular I can't seem to figure out the algebra to arrive at the expressions to the right of the word "then". I thought to solve for $x$ the author used the typical formula for solving a quadratic equation, namely:

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a}$$

So using the assumptions of $u^{2} - v^{2} = b^{2} - 4ac$ and $uv = 0$, I obtained:

$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{u^{2} - v^{2}}}{2a}$$

But I don't see how this is going to lead to

$$x = \frac{-b + u}{2a}$$

unless we assume $v = 0$, but in doing that I have no idea how the $x^{2}$ would even be possible of coming about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wondering about the "then" - that is, why are those formulas true, given that $u^2 - v^2 = b^2 - 4ac, uv = 0$, then that is a matter of noting that $uv=0$ means either $$\begin{align}u^2 &= b^2 - 4ac\\v&=0\end{align}$$ or $$\begin{align}u &= 0\\v^2 &= 4ac - b^2\end{align}$$
If you set either $u = 0$ or $v=0$ in the two expressions, you can expand them out and cancel to get an expression only in the square of the other variable, and it turns out that substituting the above expressions for the squares will make both equations true. Well, almost: Spivak or the publisher made a typo in setting the equations. It will have to be corrected to get the right result.

---

On the other hand, if you are wondering how Spivak managed to pull those particular expressions out of thin air:

1. Move $c$ to the other side and multiply by $4a$: $$4a^2x^2 +4ab x = -4ac$$
2. Note that $(2ax + b)^2 = 4a^2x^2 + 4abx+b^2$. So $$(2ax + b)^2 = b^2 - 4ac$$ or making the substitution $z = 2ax+b$, $$z^2 = b^2 - 4ac$$
3. $z$ is some complex number, so write $z = u + iv$, then $z^2 = u^2 - v^2 + 2uvi$, so $$u^2 - v^2 + 2uvi = b^2 - 4ac$$
4. Equating the real and imaginary parts of the above equation,
   $$\begin{align}u^2 - v^2 &= b^2 - 4ac\\2uv &= 0\end{align}$$ and of course the last equation can be divided by $2$.
5. $u+iv = z = 2ax+b$, so $$x = \frac{u-b}{2a} + i\frac v{2a}$$
6. $$x^2 = \left[\left(\frac{u-b}{2a}\right)^2 - \left(\frac v{2a}\right)^2\right] + \left[2\left(\frac{u-b}{2a}\right)\left(\frac v{2a}\right)\right]i$$
   so
   $$\begin{align}ax^2 + bx + c = &\left\{a\left[\left(\frac{u-b}{2a}\right)^2 - \left(\frac v{2a}\right)^2\right]+ b\left[\frac{u-b}{2a}\right] + c\right\}\\&+ \left\{a\left[2\left(\frac{u-b}{2a}\right)\left(\frac v{2a}\right)\right]+b\left[\frac v{2a}\right]\right\}i\end{align}$$

and to be $0$, both its real and imaginary parts must be $0$.

Comment: For a person with some experience doing this sort of work I would've never seen the construction that you explained. That was bloody nifty, sleek, and pretty. How long and what experience did you need to be able to view a question in this sort of way? I'm definitely going to be taking the approach you used away from this. Thanks a lot for the assistance.

Comment: Well, it is basically just completing the square on the quadratic, and then examining it as a complex number equation and splitting it into real and imaginary parts. Both are well-known tricks. I actually started it by dividing by $a$, but then I had to consider how best to match everything Spivak produced and decided the easiest way to explain it was to multiply through by $4a$ instead, which I think he did to avoid fractions as long as possible.

Comment: I think it is my lack of practice of considering of things in the form of complex numbers that has me uneasy still. In due time it will change.